# Get characters before the underscore

Tags: pandas, string, split

I have a pandas dataframe in the below format

```
  name
  BC_new-0
  BC_new-1
  BC_new-2
```

Would like to extract whatever is below the "_" and append it to a new column

```
  df['value'] = str(df['name']).split("_")[0]
```

But I get the below results

```
  value
  0 BC
  0 BC
  0 BC
```

Any suggestions on how this "0" could not be present in the output. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you meant `df['value'] = df['name'].str.split("_")[0]` [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) not [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: @HenryEcker: I could not do that as i get this error - ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (1231)

Comment: Oops. I missed a `str` -> `df['value'] = df['name'].str.split("_").str[0]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I might use `str.extract` here:

```py
df['value'] = df['name'].str.extract(r'^([^_]+)')
```

As the comment above suggests, if you want to use string splitting, then use `str.split`:

```py
df['value'] = df['name'].str.split("_").str[0]
```

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake above. Need another `str` to get `[0]` from each row -> `df['value'] = df['name'].str.split("_").str[0]`

Comment: df['name'].str.split("_").str[0]